# How to query data from synonyms using odp.net managed driver in c#?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net-managed

I have a connexion to a service in which I only have access to synonyms (i.e., I cannot create any view, procedure, ...) and I intent to query data from them. I'm using ODP.NET managed driver to do so but until now I found nothing to achieve that. I'm left with hard-coding all the queries but before doing that I wanted to ask if it's possible somehow to map c# classes to oracle synonyms if that makes sense at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know nothing about what you are doing, but - as far as Oracle synonyms are concerned - you shouldn't worry. From your point of view, you'd query data as if they were tables or views, no difference.

Comment: @Littlefoot I used EF Power tools to generate the code first models but no model for the synonyms were generated hence the question. So if I create a model with same name of the synonym it would query the data as if it were from a table?

Comment: Sorry, dcg; Andre has already answered what you've asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping c# classes to database entities is typically done with an object relational mapper like Entity Framework. Unfortunately, the Oracle provider for EF doesn't support synonyms ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/entityUnsupported.htm#ODPNT8317)).

Personally I would give a MicroORM like [PetaPoco](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco), [NPoco](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco) or [Massive](https://github.com/FransBouma/Massive) a try.

All of those options give you the possibility to map query results to classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll take a look into those.